# Assign Custom Layer's Weight from 1D to 2D

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I am writing a custom layer in Tensorflow 2.0 and I ran to a problem as follow:

I want to transform a 1D weight array (5x1) to a 2D array (10x10). Suppose I have the index to transform from 1D to 2D as follow, weight_index_lst:

```
weight_id, row, col
1,5,6
2,6,7
3,7,8
4,8,9
5,9,10
```

The others location of the 2D array will just get a value of 0. Here's my script for the custom layers. My input is in (10x1) shape. For the w_mat, it receives 0 anywhere else that self.w is not assigned

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers

class mylayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, weight_index_lst, **kwargs):
        super(mylayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.weight_index_lst= weight_index_lst

    def build(self):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape = (5,1),
                                 initializer = 'he_normal',
                                 trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):          
        ct = 0
        w_mat = tf.Variable(np.zeros((21, 21)),dtype='float32',trainable=False)
        for i in range(20):
            i1 = self.weight_index_lst[i,1] #row index
            i2 = self.weight_index_lst[i,2] #column index
            w_mat[i1,i2].assign(self.w[ct,0]) #problem with no gradient provided
            #or w_mat[i1,i2] = self.w[ct,0] #resource variable cannot be assigned
            ct = ct+1

        y = tf.matmul(w_mat,inputs)           
        return y
```

I could have declared a (10x10) weight array but my deep learning wants the others weight to be 0 and cannot be trained.

Comment: Please let me know if the answers below worked for you. If not please clarify what issues you've seen with it or why it's not what you were looking for. If the answer worked for you please consider accepting it by clicking on the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to specifically create a new layer with the weights and such then the resolution to your problem (no gradients propagating through assign) is to change all of your operations to be symbolic tensor operations - then TF will be able to propagate the gradients. One way to do so is to create 1d tensor of weights you want to train, append non-trainable const tensor with 0.0 value and then use `tf.gather` to select the needed weights and/or constant zero for each of `n**2` elements of the matrix you want to use to multiply the layer's input by. Since all operations are symbolic tensor operations TF will be able to propagate gradients with no problems. Code of such approach below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np

class mylayer(layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, n, weight_index_lst, **kwargs):
        super(mylayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.weight_index_lst = weight_index_lst
        self.n = n

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.w = self.add_weight(shape = (len(self.weight_index_lst),),
                                 initializer = 'he_normal',
                                 trainable = True)

    def call(self, inputs):
        const_zero = tf.constant([0.], dtype=tf.float32)
        const_zero_and_weights = tf.concat([const_zero, self.w], axis=0)
        ct = 1 # start with 1 since 0 means take the non-trainable 0. from const_zero_and_weights
        selector = np.zeros((self.n ** 2), dtype=np.int32) # indicies
        for i, j in self.weight_index_lst:
            selector[i * self.n + j] = ct
            ct = ct+1
        t_ind = tf.constant(selector, dtype=tf.int32)
        w_flattened = tf.gather(const_zero_and_weights, t_ind)
        w_matrix = tf.reshape(w_flattened, (self.n, self.n))
        y = tf.matmul(w_matrix, inputs)           
        return y

m = tf.keras.Sequential([
    layers.Dense(21**2, input_shape=(45,)),
    layers.Reshape(target_shape=(21,21)),
    mylayer(21, [(4,5), (5,6), (6,7), (7,8), (8,9)]),
    ])
m.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I am trying to scale the problems up (increasing n) and I encounter the ValueError: Tried to convert 'indices' to a tensor and failed. Error: Cannot create a tensor proto whose content is larger than 2GB. It seems to occur from the tf.gather, do we have anyway to work around it? I am thinking of placeholder and tf.session

Comment: The problem is not likely caused by tf.gather - it is likely happening at `tf.constant` call. I'm not sure I see an easy way to resolve that except an ugly solution which is to split selector array into smaller piecies (e.g. k tensors of size (n/k * n)) and then concatenate them together to use inside `tf.gather`. Also it is a bit suspicious that you need to have such a large matrix with this type of selection (`n` should be at least `23,171`). Do you have a sparse matrix there maybe? I would suggest to post as a separate question.

Comment: Yes, I'm working on a city network where each road intersection is a node. There are 60k nodes in this network. I already tested the script on a 21 nodes network and it run perfectly fine.

Comment: For sparse matrix I would suggest to use dedicated sparse tensors functionality.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to create a trainable layer for this. Consider just using non-trainable lambda layer:

```
def select_as_needed(x, wrc, n):
    selector = np.zeros(n * n, dtype=np.int32) # tensor with the index of input element we want to select in each cell (0 otherwise)
    mask = np.zeros(n * n, dtype=np.float32) # 0./1. tensor with ones only on the positions where we put some selected element
    for w, r, c in wrc:
        selector[r * n + c] = w
        mask[r * n + c] = 1.0
    t_ind = tf.constant(selector, dtype=tf.int32)
    t_mask = tf.constant(mask, dtype=tf.float32)
    return tf.gather(x, t_ind, axis=1) * mask # if we don't multiply by mask the 0-index value of input will go to all positions for which we didn't select anything

wrc = [(0,4,5), (1,5,6), (2,6,7), (3,7,8), (4,8,9)] # same as your table, but 0-based
n = 10
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    # ... your stuff
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, 'linear'), # output of 5 neurons (or replace with whatever else you have which is producing 5 outputs per sample)
    tf.keras.layers.Lambda(select_as_needed, arguments={'wrc': wrc, 'n':n}),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(target_shape=(n, n)),
])
```